# Check if EditText is empty while calculating numbers

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to build an age calculator application. When I didn't enter a number in one of the `EditTexts` and click on calculate `Button`, my app is crashed! ["App has stopped" and click the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuCO1.png)

I tried to set `yearbirth.isEmpty() || yearbirth.equals("") || yearbirth == null` , but nothing worked.

CODE:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
var yearage:Int?= null
var monthage:Int?= null
var dayage:Int?= null

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    buGetAge.setOnClickListener({
        val year= Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month= Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day= Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        var yearage = year - Integer.parseInt(yearbirth.text.toString()) -1
        val monthage:Int?
        val dayage:Int?

        if (yearbirth== null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have to enter your year berth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            if (month < Integer.parseInt(monthbirth.text.toString())){
                monthage=(Integer.parseInt(monthbirth.text.toString())- month- 12)* -1
            }else if (month > Integer.parseInt(monthbirth.text.toString())) {
                yearage=year- Integer.parseInt(yearbirth.text.toString())
                monthage= (Integer.parseInt(monthbirth.text.toString())- month)* -1
            }else {
                yearage=year- Integer.parseInt(yearbirth.text.toString())
                monthage=0
            }
            if (day < Integer.parseInt(daybirth.text.toString())){
                dayage= (Integer.parseInt(daybirth.text.toString())- day- 30)* -1
            }else if (day > Integer.parseInt(daybirth.text.toString())){
                dayage= day- Integer.parseInt(daybirth.text.toString())
            }else {
                dayage=0
            }

            val a= (yearage* 12)+ monthage
            val b= (a * 30)+ dayage

            val ageinyears= "$yearage years"
            val ageinmonths= "$a months"
            val ageindays= "$b days"

            txtshow.text = "Your age is $yearage years, $monthage months and $dayage days"
            txtshow2.text = "\nYOUR AGE:\nin years:\n\nin months:\n\nin days:"
            txtshow3.text = "\n\n$ageinyears \n\n$ageinmonths \n\n $ageindays "

            this.yearage=yearage
            this.monthage=monthage
            this.dayage=dayage
        }
    })
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of the photo of the crash, wich everybody knows how it looks like, try put some crash log here

Answer (score 1):

Verify that `yearbirth.text.toString()` is not empty before attempting to parse it into an Integer (and also if it's a valid integer.)

To achieve so, put the line you showed in your code:

```
var yearage = year - Integer.parseInt(yearbirth.text.toString()) -1
```

Inside an `if` verifying that the input is valid, like so:

```
if(yearbirth.text.toString().matches(Regex("\\d+")))
    var yearage = year - Integer.parseInt(yearbirth.text.toString()) -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for empty `Input` like this:

```
newString = Integer.toString(yearbirth).trim();
if (newString.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "EditText is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Then add crash report to see what is going on..In android studio ,`tools/android/android device monitor` from devices tab choose your device, then in `logcat` section hit `add` button and, set a name for your app in `filter name` and add your package name in `by application name`. run your app and see the crash reports. and if you are using another IDE then search in google about how to get app log in your IDE

Comment: @S.R your method involves unnecessary allocations. Apart from that, there's a built-in method `.isNullOrBlank()` for this: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-null-or-blank.html